# Is there any way to set up an rtfmp server on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash, rtmfp

I am currently recreating a server for an old multiplayers flash game, I have all the php parts of the server reasonably recreated in node.js but the game also used rtfmp to initiate p2p. Not using rtmfp is not an option, do not suggest it. The closest thing I have found is a node module called ArcusNode, and it looks like it would work fine if it didnt have missing modules that seem to be made in c++ that I cant compile no matter how hard I try.

Ive tried complaining arcus on my own pc and was given hundreds of errors in return, I tried compiling it on the server but it seems like it didnt get all the files, Ive looked everywhere for some sort of precompiled version and found nothing. I dont see any other real ways of running an rtmfp server that isnt downloading 10 (ten) malwares off of some random free download now site to get adobe media server 3.5 or some other software that promises the same thing. I dont even know where to begin.

Comment: This should be checked, as the info is like 10-15 years old, but still. Back then there were at least two alternatives to the **Adobe Media Server**: 1) **Red5**: open-source, free of charge, **Java**-based, and 2) **Wowza**: some third-party solution, not open-source and not free, but still much cheaper than original one form the **Adobe**. There also could probably be other ones I am not aware of. The point is to find a suitable and hopefully up-to-date and still supported alternative. Hope, that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ArcusNode is no longer maintained. We have built [MonaServer](https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaServer2) which support RTMFP but how do you implement the client side? For Javascript you should create a new wrapper of a c++ library like [librtmfp](https://github.com/MonaSolutions/librtmfp) but it requires time to map the C++ functions to JS.

What about rewriting your code to use WebRTC which is supported by browsers and node.js? This is the new way to go for p2p over the web.

Comment: The thing is is that its not my code, its a random flash game (Im just making the server again, not the game). I was hoping to do something like just changing the server url because editing the swf is a pain to do for anything more than simple changes. Ill look at getting MonaServer working again.

Comment: Mona worked perfectly using localhost, I havent gotten it running on an external server but this should be just file for anyone who finds this question

Comment: Ok great, it should run correctly from an external server as well, don't forget to setup UDP forwarding for port 1935.